# node/express 4: displaying errors with express-validator on ajax post

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, validation, express

I'm new to node and trying to show validation errors (using express-validator and express 4) when a user tries to submit a form.

The validator seem to work since if I log the data to console everything is as expected. However, I cannot display the errors on the page when I render the view (nothing is displayed). The only difference with the "standard" tutorials I have been following on express validation, is that I'm posting the data with AJAX.

My code is below. I use *[...]* to indicate that there is more code I removed, and I stripped down some of the form fields for brevity.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , indexController = require('./routes/index')
  , membersController = require('./routes/members')
  [...]
  , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var app = express();

[...]
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator()) // tried both placing it here or below
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// I realize this may be not optimal
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexController);
app.use('/members', membersController);

[...]
module.exports = app;
```

**handle_members.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#join_btn').click(function(event, req, res){
    event.preventDefault(); 

      var newMember = {
                      'name': $('#join_form input#join_name').val(),
                      'email': $('#join_form input#join_email').val()
                      }

      $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data: newMember,
              url: '/members/addmember',
              dataType: 'JSON'
              }).done(function(response){
                if (response.msg === 'success'){
                  alert('New member added successfully!')
                }
                // maybe this is not necessary?
                else if (response.msg === 'validation'){  
                    alert('validation failed');
                }
                else{
                  alert('Error: ' + response.msg)
                }
              });        
  });     
});
```

**members.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/addmember',validator, function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('memberstest');
    collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: 'success' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});


function validator(req, res, next) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'not valid email').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('name', 'cannot be empty').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        console.log(errors) // these are as expected
        res.render('index',{errors:errors}); // no errors displayed
        }
    else {
        next();
    }
};

module.exports = router;
```

**index.jade**

```
        [...]
                form#join_form(method='POST', action='', role='form')
                    div.form-group
                        input#join_name.form-control(type='text', name='join_name')
                        input#join_email.form-control(type='email', name='email')
                    button#join_btn.btn(type='button') join

                if errors
                    ul
                        for error in errors
                            li = error.msg
          [...]
```

The errors variable when logged to console looks like this:

```
[ { param: 'email', msg: 'not valid email', value: 'xxxx' },   { param: 'name', msg: 'can't be empty', value: '' } ]
```

In the past couple of days I really tried a lot of different things but none of them worked. The problem seem to be always the same: all good but when I render the view is like it never enters the "if errors ..." statement. Maybe there is something very basic I'm missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

PS. Eventually the form ideally should be inside a modal/pop-up, in case that changes something.

Comment: Can you show how the errors variable looks like?

Comment: @MarceloAlves sure I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First attempt

Try to add the validator middleware immediately after any of the bodyParser middlewares, like the [documentation](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) asks to:

```
var express = require('express')
  , indexController = require('./routes/index')
  , membersController = require('./routes/members')
  [...]
  , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var app = express();

[...]
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator()); // this line must be immediately after any of the bodyParser middlewares!
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// I realize this may be not optimal
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexController);
app.use('/members', membersController);

[...]
module.exports = app;
```

---

## Second attempt

Based on the documentation, errors seems to be an array of objects with the `msg` and `param` properties. Try to update your jade code to the following:

```
ul
  if errors
    each error, i in errors
      li #{error.msg}
```

---

## Third attempt

After analyzing the code that the OP provided me through Github, I found the problem. The OP is sending the data to the backend using an Ajax call, and responding it using [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), which is clearly wrong, since `res.render` isn't to respond requests made with Ajax, the right method to do this is [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json).

Example:

Call `/addmember` endpoint using jQuery:

```
var data = {}; // data here

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  url: '/addmember',
  dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function() {
  alert('done');
}).fail(function() {
  alert('fail');
});
```

Answer it from the backend using `res.json`:

```
router.post('/addmember', (req, res) => {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('memberstest');
  collection.insert(req.body, (error, result) => {
    if (error)
      return res.json({ error });
    return res.json({ result });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried that. It has been in that spot all the time, I actually tried to move it as one of my latest attempts and forgot to put it back up when I copied the code here.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but doesn't seem to work. I did not include in my answer but even avoiding the loop, I just tried to show a test paragraph in case of errors and that does not show up either. That makes me guess the problem is not in the jade loop but somewhere else. It seems it never enters that if statement at all. By the way, what's the "i"  in this second attempt? You don't seem to use it.

Comment: It's already there at https://github.com/thomscot/defender . There is no docs though as it's quite at early stages. Also, there is a lot of text in Japanese, hope that's not too confusing. Ah, well the latest changes and validation attempts aren't pushed yet of course so not sure how that can help.

Comment: What steps do I need to do to create the server? I already run `npm install` and `node app.js`.

Comment: The application does not have some codes that you have posted in your answer. Can you commit everything that is missing?

Comment: "npm start" should be enough (see the script in package.json). I can update the answer later but I'm afraid it would just get too long. Can you look at the full code on github? Basically everything is the same except for all the validation-related things added here. Well, one difference is that the form has more items and is inside a modal on github.

Comment: I saw, but `.bin/www` doesn't exist in your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150556/discussion-between-tommy-and-marcelo-alves).

Comment: I'm glad to help you Tommy! :)